# Issue with compiling HTML5 code in Web-Browser

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

i'v created demo page of mobile jquery using TextEdit...which is,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>My Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

but, in my browser code is not getting compiled and it shows these texts as it is as plain text.. and i'v confirmed that my browser support HTML5 here: http://html5test.com/

what is missing!?

Comment: What browser are you using because this page is working correctly in Firefox?

Comment: Do you have valid extension for the file?

Comment: @Gajotres: actually i have tried in firefox and crome too.. both have some reason.. check this
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=54d36a&s=5

Comment: @Nil: i think yes, check this image..
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=54d36a&s=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry but issue was weird, actually i had created that page using textEdit which stored all text as rich text format which may not recognized to be compiled as html... so i converted that text to plain text and saved it again and that worked!!

thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Question is what browser are you using? I tried your code with Chrome and it worked perfectly.

[image]

My guess is that you are behind a corporate or university firewall that is blockign your CDN urls. So why don't you download the jQuery mobile files and place the js, css files locally and try to run the page again?

Answer (score 0):

```
src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @BaSha When working with HTML5 today, many of you know that you'll need to include the "HTML5 shiv" to ensure that CSS will recognize and be able to style those elements in browsers that aren't yet hip to HTML5